# Redirects with Amazon S3 and CloudFront

Tags: redirect, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to setup some redirects using route configurations on an S3 bucket. What I did is setup the static web hosting with this redirection rules

```
<RoutingRules>
  <RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
      <KeyPrefixEquals>test/</KeyPrefixEquals>
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
      <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>anothertest/</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
    </Redirect>
  </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

So each requests to `<my-s3-bucket>/test/*` will be redirected to `<my-s3-bucket>/anothertest/*`
If I do this using the S3 static website URL it works, however if I do using the CloudFront URL that is associated with this origin it didn't. Is anything particular I need to do in order to make it work from CloudFront too? Also, I noticed that if I change the redirect target, say I don't want `anothertest` but `alsoatest`, the rule did not update properly and instead still redirects to `anothertest`, so is somehow caching the redirect

Comment: <HostName>...</HostName> use this

Comment: Thank you for your comment. In the end I ended up using a Lambda Edge attached to the CloudFront Origin Request event